# Lenovo z51-70 bios reset?

Tags: laptop

I wanted to change primary video card in BIOS to Radeon and I choose PCI graphics by mistake.

My display is now dark. I tried to connect it via hdmi to external monitor and still dark.

By any chance someone with z51-70 could tell me how to reset the bios to default by going blind?
I just need the key combination. Like press power button, FN+F2 to enter bios and then.....

PS: I am aware about resetting cmos battery but I don't want to open the laptop since is not mine and is still in warranty. Beside that I heard other people did this and bios still didn't reset.

Comment: Call Lenovo support and get assistance from them, that will be better idea.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser.StackExchange - be sure to take the tour:  https://superuser.stackexchange.com/Tour

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve the issue with these steps:

- hit power button
- quickly hit <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> to enter bios
- <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f9</kbd> (load defaults) enter
- <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f10</kbd>(save and exit) enter

After this, the laptop rebooted and I got an image on the monitor.